# Python Tkinter App to Check Status for a List of Domains

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, desktop-application

I got 2 issues that need solving please:

1. "check domain manually" doesn't work as expected. When all domains in the file are checked, I press the button again it doesn't clear old results and check again but return error "index out of range",
2. "continue checking automatically" button doesn't work as the name suggests.
   Code and image of domain file are below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import threading
import time


class DomainStatusChecker:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Domain Status Checker")

        self.domains = []
        self.num_domains = 0
        self.results = {}
        self.running = False
        self.manual_checking = False
        self.auto_checking = False
        self.error_count = 0
        self.current_domain_index = 0
        self.auto_checker_thread = None

        self.title_label = tk.Label(root, text="Kiểm Tra Tình Trạng Hoạt Động Các Máy Chủ TA-21",
                                    font=("Helvetica", 14))
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.domain_listbox = tk.Listbox(root, height=10, width=40)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.domain_listbox.yview)
        self.close_button = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=self.close_window)
        self.error_count_label = tk.Label(root, text="Số Lượng Máy Chủ Không Kết Nối: 0")
        self.check_manual_button = tk.Button(root, text="Check Domain Manually",
                                             command=self.check_next_domain_manually)
        self.check_auto_button = tk.Button(root, text="Continue Checking Automatically",
                                           command=self.toggle_auto_checking)
        self.clear_results_button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear Results and Check Manually",
                                              command=self.clear_and_check_manually)

        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.domain_listbox.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=10, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)
        self.close_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.error_count_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
        self.check_manual_button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.check_auto_button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.clear_results_button.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.domain_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.domain_listbox.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.scroll_listbox)

    def read_domains_from_file(self, filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            self.domains = ['http://' + line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
            self.num_domains = len(self.domains)

    def check_domain_status(self, domain):
        if domain in self.results:
            return self.results[domain]
        else:
            try:
                response = requests.get(domain)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    return "OK"
                else:
                    return "Error"
            except requests.ConnectionError:
                return "Connection Error"
            except Exception as e:
                return str(e)

    def check_domains_continuously(self):
        self.running = True

        while self.running:
            if not self.manual_checking and not self.auto_checking and self.domains:
                domain = self.domains.pop(0)
                status = self.check_domain_status(domain)
                self.results[domain] = status
                self.domain_listbox.insert(tk.END, f"{domain}: {status}")

                self.error_count = len(list(self.results.values())) - list(self.results.values()).count("OK")
                total_domains_checked = len(list(self.results.values()))
                self.error_count_label.config(
                    text=f"Số Lượng Máy Chủ Không Kết Nối: {self.error_count} / {total_domains_checked} ({self.num_domains})")

                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                time.sleep(1 * 60 * 60)
                self.read_domains_from_file("domains.txt")

    def clear_results(self):
        self.domain_listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.results = {}

    def close_window(self):
        self.running = False
        self.root.destroy()

    def scroll_listbox(self, event):
        self.domain_listbox.yview_scroll(-1 * (event.delta // 120), "units")

    def check_next_domain_manually(self):
        if self.auto_checker_thread and self.auto_checker_thread.is_alive():
            self.auto_checking = False
            self.auto_checker_thread.join()

        if self.current_domain_index < self.num_domains:
            self.manual_checking = True
            domain = self.domains[self.current_domain_index]
            status = self.check_domain_status(domain)
            self.results[domain] = status
            self.domain_listbox.insert(tk.END, f"{domain}: {status}")

            self.error_count = len(list(self.results.values())) - list(self.results.values()).count("OK")
            total_domains_checked = len(list(self.results.values()))
            self.error_count_label.config(
                text=f"Số Lượng Máy Chủ Không Kết Nối: {self.error_count} / {total_domains_checked} ({self.num_domains})")

            self.current_domain_index += 1

            if self.current_domain_index == self.num_domains:
                self.manual_checking = False

    def toggle_auto_checking(self):
        if self.manual_checking:
            return

        self.auto_checking = not self.auto_checking
        if self.auto_checking:
            self.auto_checker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.check_domains_continuously)
            self.auto_checker_thread.daemon = True
            self.auto_checker_thread.start()

    def clear_and_check_manually(self):
        if self.auto_checker_thread and self.auto_checker_thread.is_alive():
            self.auto_checking = False
            self.auto_checker_thread.join()
        self.current_domain_index = 0
        self.clear_results()
        self.manual_checking = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = DomainStatusChecker(root)
    app.read_domains_from_file("domains.txt")

    checker_thread = threading.Thread(target=app.check_domains_continuously)
    checker_thread.daemon = True
    checker_thread.start()

    root.mainloop()
```

As suggested the error looks like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\ta21-checkstatus\main2.py", line 109, in check_next_domain_manually
  domain = self.domains[self.current_domain_index]
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T4Fu.png)

1. After checking all domains manually. We should be able to check and display domains again
2. "Continue checking automatically" should work as expected. After pressing it, the program should run as before.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: You're using the same index (self.current_domain_index) without resetting it. Once you've checked all domains manually, this index reaches the maximum number of domains (self.num_domains), and the check function doesn't proceed further. Reset this index when you clear the results.

Also, you're not resetting self.auto_checking and self.manual_checking to False when needed.

Comment: Please focus on a single question.